# how add the action sheet in the cell of table view

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to add the action sheet in cell of table view, i want when i click on the cell of table view the action sheet should come and after i click on the the option in action sheet, i want to go to the next view.

Comment: @AlBlue Please do not use tags such as "not-a-question" and "close". If you want to close it, vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Make ur view controller implement the UITableViewDelegate and UIActionSheetDelegate and set those delegates properly

Override tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: show your ActionSheet there
Override actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex: and dismiss the ActionSheet and show the next view.