# adding view into action sheet

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet

Can I add my custom UIViewController into the ActionSheet ?

thanks

Comment: what u want explain. but u cant add a full view in an actionsheet

Comment: thanks for reply ... see I want to add a view which is subclass of uiviewcontroller. in this view i've added a image view as a back ground image and a table for display the XML parsered data. Now I want to add this view into action sheet . thats all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

finally I've find it... I've added a view which is subclass of UIViewController into the UIActionSheet. I've created a view in separate file (using xib) .

```
UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
[asheet showInView:self.view]; 
[asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 230, 320, 230)];


CustomView *innerView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomView" bundle:nil];
innerView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 210);
[asheet addSubview:innerView.view];
//[asheet addSubview:innerView];

[innerView release];
[asheet release];
```

Comment: using "[[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"a" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"destroy" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];" results in a better showing animation

Answer (score 1):

I recently created an application where I created action sheet and added a picker view in it.
Firstly you need to create object for action sheet in your .h file as along with its properties as follows :

```
UIActionSheet *menuProperty;    

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIActionSheet *menuArea;
```

Then you need to make following changes in your .m file

```
menuArea = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil  delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Done"  
                                        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];  


// Add the picker  
pickerArea = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,185,0,0)];  

pickerArea.delegate = self;  
pickerArea.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    // note this is default to NO  

[menuArea addSubview:pickerArea];  
[menuArea showInView:self.view];  
[menuArea setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 600)];
```

Comment: how to set actionsheet's height from the top ? tried with asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, 320, 210). I want to reduce from top not from bottom. thanks

Comment: I changed it to setFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,600). Works fine here.

Comment: [Action Sheet](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=301851) See this example

Answer (score -1):

i think these links will help u. i have never add a view in uiactionsheet but after a little search i think we can add.

http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=301851

[how add the action sheet in the cell of table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899154/how-add-the-action-sheet-in-the-cell-of-table-view)