# Need assistance regarding UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add UISegmentController to UIActionSheet here is my code

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Copy", @"New Key", nil];

NSArray *keyLengthOptions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Option 1", @"Option 2", nil];

UISegmentedControl *segmentController = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:keyLengthOptions];

segmentController.frame = CGRectMake(35, 0, 250, 38);

    [segmentController addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[segmentController setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

[actionSheet addSubview:segmentController];

[actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];

[actionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.tabBarController.view];
```

Every thing is working fine but `[actionSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];` is not working. How to increase the size of UIActionSheet to adjust with subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is very important. You need to call showInView: on the UIActionsheet first, then adjust its size. Here is another question that addresses this:

[adding view into action sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389925/adding-view-into-action-sheet)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you please tell me why the calling order is important in this scenario?

Comment: Because showInview: sets the bounds and center on the actionsheet. If you set the frame prior to calling showInView:, it just gets overwritten.