# Custom UIActionSheets?

Tags: iphone, uiview, sdk, uiactionsheet

My question is one that I have been wondering for a while now, and I am ready to ask it. In my app, I have a flat unique design in which the default UIActionSheet design does not match.

My question is, how would I go about changing the design, or better yet: Could I create a UIView with the button(s) and add it to the view each time I want my custom created UIActionSheet to show?

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from creating your own custom view class that behaves like a `UIActionSheet` but with whatever look and feel you want.

Comment: So I would just add that view as a subview then? How would I get the animation effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this library :

[BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets](https://github.com/gpambrozio/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets)

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this without third-party libraries?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5391383/1272540 they add a UIView to the UIActionSheet